# how to add a comment field in php

Tags: php, html

i have a php page which has a textarea for accepting user review and another field displaying all the comments entered by the user.
A button is used to add review, User when clicks on the button, the page should be reloaded and the Comments section will had this review added at top.
I am able to display the button and performing all database operations on a separate php page and linking it to the current page.
Is there any way i can do these database update of current section in the same page, such that when user clicks on the button, it immediately follows with the database opeartions and then reloads the page? Some rough code such as:

```
<input type='button' name='Add review' value ='Add review' onclick='add_review();'>
<?php 
if (<Add review> button press is true){
//perform the function
function add_review(){
<database opeartions...>
}
}
```

Is this possible in php

Answer (score 1):

No, the onclick is Javascript only. But you can do what you want by changing the order of things.

You don't go into detail about what you are trying to do, but a common approach is as follows:

```
<?php
if (isset($_RESULT['addreview'])){
    //perform the database operations
    // Redirect to same page to clear query string and set fields to default
    header('Location: yourpage.php'); The URL of this page
    exit();
}
?>
<form action="#" ...>
   ...user input fields
   <input type='submit' name='addreview' value ='Add review'>
</form>
```

When the user clicks the submit, the page will be submitted (to itself). You don't need the onclick. Your PHP gets the values passed in the form variables and updates the database. The page is then redisplayed.

Note the change in the input; input names cannot have spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So should it be something like :               <?php
if (isset($_POST["Add review"])){
    //perform the database operations
}
?>
So when the page loads ,it checks if Add review button is clicked and if it is, will perform the operation?

Comment: Right. But you'll need to change the name. An HTML name cannot have blanks in it. 'addreview' would work.

Comment: Ok. but when i moved the button press bit to the start of the page, the page updates the review everytime i refresh the page. So even without the button click, the update query still runs and i end up getting the same review added that many times i refresh.  Is there any alternate way to  if (isset($_POST["Addreview"])), to get if the user has clicked the button instead of refresh.

Comment: The problem is not the test for submit, but not clearing out the values from the previous submit. I added to the answer to show how to redirect the page to itself, which resets everything as it was in the beginning.